# Does this function have a limit (complex function)?

Tags: calculus, analysis, complex-analysis

I am trying to find if $$\lim_{r\to0}\frac{r(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta) + i|r|\sqrt{|\cos\theta\sin\theta|}}{e^{i\theta}}$$ has a limit.

Does the limit tend to $0$ as $r\to0$? Because the numerator will be $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This* limit does exist.  But if this is supposed to be following up on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80847/is-fxiy-x2-y2-i-sqrtxy-complex-differentiable) question, then what you need is
$$\lim_{r\to0}\frac{r(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta) + i(|r|/r)\sqrt{|\cos\theta\sin\theta|}}{e^{i\theta}},$$
with $|r|/r$ rather than just $r$ in the second term in the numerator.  Then notice that $|r|/r=1$ if $r>0$ and $=-1$ if $r<0$.  The first term then approaches $0$ as $r\to0$, but the second term approaches different limits as $r\to0+$ and as $r\to0-$.  So the limit you would be looking for does not exist because the two one-sided limits differ (except when $\cos\theta\sin\theta=0$).